# Virtual Desktop Icon missing

Tags: kubuntu

For some mysterious reason the virtual desktop icon from the kubuntu 10.10 panel has disappeared. How could I added it back to the panel?

Comment: click on the cashew, or maybe just the little up triangle. You might have hidden it.

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on the panel, select *Panel Options -> Add Widgets*, search for *Pager* and just drag it to the panel or double click it.